# Is there any problem with pandas shift method to create lag values?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create lagged values for my data. I was using for loop as I had to include around 100 lagged values. But the problem is pandas method 'shift' is throwing an error after creating one lagged value.

For Example when I use

```py
data1['lag_1']=data1.shift(1)
```

It is generating column for one lagged value.

But when the same code is run for the next lagged value, it is throwing an error.

```py
data1['lag_2']=data1.shift(2)
```

I wanted to execute this in for loop as I want to create 100 lagged values columns but this shift does not seem to work.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-93-bc545991b12c>", line 1, in <module>
    data1['lag_2']=data1.shift(2)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3370, in __setitem__
    self._set_item(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3446, in _set_item
    NDFrame._set_item(self, key, value)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 3172, in _set_item
    self._data.set(key, value)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1056, in set
    self.insert(len(self.items), item, value)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\managers.py", line 1158, in insert
    placement=slice(loc, loc + 1))

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 3095, in make_block
    return klass(values, ndim=ndim, placement=placement)

  File "C:\Users\k0932146\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\blocks.py", line 87, in __init__
    '{mgr}'.format(val=len(self.values), mgr=len(self.mgr_locs)))

ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1
```

Also I wanted to implement it for 100 lag values, is there any efficient way to create these lag values?

Comment: provide sample data

Comment: Even with the folowing commands it is not working

x=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1000))

x["lag1"]=x.shift(1)
x["lag2"]=x.shift(2)

Comment: that is because some next values might not be available in the loop

Comment: may be add a condition to test if it is available before you assign/use

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this error is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is number of columns in your dataframe.

Intially you have only one column in your dataframe so it `shift` takes only column present in dataframe.

```
data1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10))
data1['lag_1']=data1.shift(1)
print(data1)
```

output:

```
    0   lag_1
0   0   NaN
1   1   0.0
2   2   1.0
3   3   2.0
4   4   3.0
5   5   4.0
6   6   5.0
7   7   6.0
8   8   7.0
9   9   8.0
```

Now your dataframe has 2 columns but `shift` can be applied only on single column so it is throwing en error.

Instead apply `shift` on a column :

```
data1['lag_2']=data1[0].shift(2)
```

Output:

```
    0   lag_1   lag_2
0   0   NaN     NaN
1   1   0.0     NaN
2   2   1.0     0.0
3   3   2.0     1.0
4   4   3.0     2.0
5   5   4.0     3.0
6   6   5.0     4.0
7   7   6.0     5.0
8   8   7.0     6.0
9   9   8.0     7.0
```

**Edit**

For 100 lagged values you can do:

```
for i in range(100):
  col = "lag_{}".format(i+1)
  data1[col] = data1[0].shift(i+1)
```

Comment: from his question, he seem to be using it in a `for loop`

Comment: @MEdwin Edited answer accordingly

Comment: data1[col] = data1[0].shift(i+1)   This  code is giving key error.    Also I tried with iloc and loc but these methods only select the first row not column , I know we can select the first column using data1.iloc[:,0] and then converting it to dataframe to apply shift method but is there any efficient method to do this?

Comment: @Bhakti, instead of `data1[0]`, try to use `data1['columname']`.

Answer (score 0):

As assume that the original `data1` dataframe has one single column. So when you write:

```
data1['lag_1']=data1.shift(1)
```

you are assigning a single column dataframe into a new column, which is fine.

But on second pass when you write:

```
data1['lag_2']=data1.shift(2)
```

you now assign a 2 columns dataframe into a single column which does no longer make sense. You should do:

```
data1['lag_2']=data1.iloc[:,0].shift(2)
```

in order to shift and copy only the first column.